# D3 bar chart zoom

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to add zoom functionality on svg grouped bar chart using d3.js. The graph has started zooming however it is going outside the graph area. Also, it is not able to zoom in the axis property. Can anyone suggest a fix?

Code / HTML to replicate the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/47L61oq8/

JavaScript code to zoom:

```
var x = d3.select("svg defs clipPath rect").attr("x");
        var y = d3.select("svg defs clipPath rect").attr("y");
        var width = d3.select("svg defs clipPath rect").attr("width");
        var height = d3.select("svg defs clipPath rect").attr("height");

        var svg = d3.select("svg");
        var zoom = d3.zoom()
            .scaleExtent([1, Infinity])
            .translateExtent([
                [x, y],
                [width, height]
            ])
            .extent([
                [x, y],
                [width, height]
            ])
            .on("zoom", zoom);

        svg.call(zoom);

        function zoom() {

            var rects = d3.selectAll("svg g rect");

            var xAxis = d3.selectAll("svg g.x-axis");
            var yAxis = d3.selectAll("svg g.y-axis");

            var t = d3.event.transform;
            rects.attr("transform", t);

            xAxis.attr("transform", d3.zoomIdentity.translate(t.x, height).scale(t.k));
            xAxis.selectAll("text")
                .attr("transform", d3.zoomIdentity.scale(1 / t.k));
            xAxis.selectAll("line")
                .attr("transform", d3.zoomIdentity.scale(1 / t.k));

            yAxis.attr("transform", d3.zoomIdentity.translate(0, t.y).scale(t.k));
            yAxis.selectAll("text")
                .attr("transform", d3.zoomIdentity.scale(1 / t.k));
            yAxis.selectAll("line")
                .attr("transform", d3.zoomIdentity.scale(1 / t.k));

        }
```

Comment: How do you want the zoom to work?  Something like [this](https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoomable-bar-chart)?

Comment: Yes, like the given example. Note that the example I have is grouped bar chart. Thanks.

Comment: Here is a running codepen for zoomable grouped bar char [D3.js examples and sandbox](https://codepen.io/medeirosrich/pen/bvRORN) by  [Richard](https://codepen.io/medeirosrich)

Comment: Thanks @Richard - I came across the link too. The given example is adding zoom functionality while creating the graph. While I have an SVG already created by a third-party provider and I am extending the SVG to add zoom functionality.